# Does JavaScript shift() method returns reference or copy of the element?

Tags: javascript, reference, pass-by-reference

Lets say i have tree objects declared like this:

```
var obj1 = new Car();
var obj2 = new Car();
var obj3 = new Car();
```

and i put them in an array

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(obj1);
myArray.push(obj2);
myArray.push(obj3);
```

and finally if i do exactly this:

```
var firstElement = myArray.shift();
```

it makes me wonder:

Is **firstElement** a reference to **obj1** or is it a copy of it? For example if i change some property of **firstElement** will it affect the **obj1** variable?

Comment: If it's an object, it's a copy... of the reference. But all you're pushing is `undefined`, since you've not created any objects.

Comment: well, you are right! I will fixe it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By reference, check out this jsfiddle for proof:

http://jsfiddle.net/3wntu/1/

HTML:

```
<div >Shifted obj title: <span  id='display1'></span></div>
<div >firstObj title: <span  id='display2'></span></div>
<div >obj1 title: <span  id='display3'></span></div>
```

js:

```
var myArray = [],
    firstElement = {},
    obj1 = {title:'obj1'},
    obj2 = {title: 'obj2'},
    obj3 = {title: 'obj3'};

myArray.push(obj1);
myArray.push(obj2);
myArray.push(obj3);

firstElement = myArray.shift();

document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = firstElement.title;

//change the objects name
firstObj.title = "firstElement";

//output the reference object title
document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = firstElement.title;

//output the original output - should be the same as the altered reference title
document.getElementById("display3").innerHTML = obj1.title;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** It's (a copy of) the element. But what is the element? Like in Java, every value in JavaScript is either a primitive or a reference (pointer to an object). "Objects" are not values in JavaScript. Objects are only manipulated through references (pointers to objects).

> Lets say i have tree objects declared like this:
>
> var obj1 = new Car(); var obj2 = new Car(); var obj3 = new Car();
>
> and i put them in an array

No. You actually have three references (pointers to objects), that point to objects that you created. You put these references in the array.

> Is firstElement a reference to obj1 or is it a copy of it? For example
>   if i change some property of firstElement will it affect the obj1
>   variable?

`firstElement` is a copy of `obj1`, a reference. If you change some property of the object pointed to by `firstElement`, then of course it can be visible though `obj1`, since they point to the same object.